# Is there any difference in result between quadratic programming VS linear programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, control-theory, optimal-control, quadratic-programming

Assume that we want to solve this equation:

$$ Ax \leq b$$

So we can either use Quadratic Programming:

$$J_{max}: x^TQx + c^Tx$$
$$Ax \leq b$$
$$x \geq 0$$

Or Linear Programming:
$$J_{max}: c^Tx$$
$$Ax \leq b$$
$$x \geq 0$$

Where $Q = A^TA$ and $c = A^Tb$

So what's the difference when I try to find the best $x$ value?
They both solve the problem. But they are different values.
Is QP more optimal?

**Practical GNU Octave Example:**

Linear programming VS Quadratic programming.

Download this [lmpc.m](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Matavecontrol/blob/master/sourcecode/lmpc.m) file and run it with this code:

[image]

Now add this code line

```
u = qp([], alp, -clp, [], [], [], [], [], alp, blp);
```

like this:

[image]

When we run the function again, then we get this result.

[image]

I'm seeking the best choice of selecting QP VS LP if I want to find $U$ from this equation:

$$r = PHI*x + GAMMA*U$$

Ass you can see, for LP, the objective function is:

```
c = (GAMMA'*GAMMA)'*(r - PHI*x)
```

And the constraints are:

```
A = GAMMA'*GAMMA
b = GAMMA'*(r - PHI*x)
```

For QP, the objective function is:

```
H = GAMMA'*GAMMA
c = -((GAMMA'*GAMMA)'*(r - PHI*x)) % Must have negative sign, else unstable!
```

And the constratins are:

```
A = GAMMA'*GAMMA
b = GAMMA'*(r - PHI*x)
```

If we now compare the outputs between LP and QP. What can we say about that? LP gives a more smoother result, but the output is like an impulse. While QP have more oscillating result?

[image]

Comment: How is $ Ax \leq b$ an equation?

Comment: Isn't LP always convex? Can't QP be non-convex? Looks like an important difference to me.

Comment: Since $Ax \leq b$ does not have a unique solution, there's no reason to expect that you'd get the same answer with both approaches.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes it can. You can solve QP-problems using modified simplex method.

Comment: @littleO which one do you perfer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am interpreting that you want to find a feasible solution to $Ax \le b, x \ge 0$.  (If the non-negative constraint is not needed, you might like to remove them).

In that case, you just have to solve

$$\min 0 $$
subject to $$Ax \le b$$
$$x \ge 0$$

Note that every linear programming problem is actually a quadratic programming problem with $Q=0$.

You can also define your own objective value like what you did in the question.

When you say a solution is more optimal, we have to state in what sense do we mean a solution is better than another solution.

Notice that $\min f(x)$ is equivalent to $-\max (-f(x))$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is a maximization problem  :)

Comment: I see $\max 0$ then. In that case, notice that you might have problem with your quadratic programming approach. You are maximizing a convex function.

Comment: Ok. So when trying to find a solution for $Ax \leq b $ then LP is a better tool than QP?

Comment: I mean your current formulation would be problematic, you can let $Q=-A^TA$ to make the objective function concave after all. I think separating modelling and solving is important. what do you mean by "better"?

Comment: Better means more suitable for the solution. If using $Q$ with the optimization, cause more expensive programming and linear programming gives a solution with less expensive programming. Then LP is a much better choice. I'm trying to decide if I should use QP or LP in model predictive control.

Comment: btw, what algorithm are you going to use to solve ur QP? what algorithm are you using to solve ur LP?

Comment: I'm using Simplex method for LP and I'm trying to use Wolfe's modified simplex method to solve QP. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7pTsl-471Yo

Comment: So for the case where the objective value is $0$, both approach are based on simplex algorithms... and you are done the moment you find a feasible solution by introducing the slack variable. ... just use simplex then.

Comment: Hold on a minute! I'm going to give you a practical GNU Octave example the difference between LP and QP. I will answer your question soon.

Comment: So if I say that the $H$ matrix in QP is 0, then I can just use SImplex ans usual? I know that. But I have changed my question with lots of pictures. This might intrest you?

Comment: I know that in this case, I'm using QP where I'm trying ti minimize and LP function where I'm trying to maximize. But the goal is to see if QP performs better than LP.

Comment: if you have a new question, post a new question? you might like to check if you are maximizing a convex function (not advisable). Also, you might like to study its contour.

Comment: Thank you. I will think about it. I think I have made my choice now. LP is  much better choice than QP if I just want to have a smooth and simple output.